# Knockout - Join Template with viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I am trying to associate the viewmodel with a html page in `KnockoutJS`.

The viewmodel is defined in an external file. And the html page has a reference to this viewmodel. I am using `requirejs` to load the file dependencies.

```js
define(['knockout-latest'], function (ko) {
 var SimpleListModel = function(items) {
  this.items = ko.observableArray(items);
  this.itemToAdd = ko.observable("");
  this.addItem = function() {
   if (this.itemToAdd() != "") {
    this.items.push(this.itemToAdd()); // Adds the item. Writing to the "items" observableArray causes any associated UI to update.
    this.itemToAdd(""); // Clears the text box, because it's bound to the "itemToAdd" observable
   }
  }.bind(this);  // Ensure that "this" is always this view model
 };
  
 ko.applyBindings(new SimpleListModel(["Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma"]));
 //return SimpleListModel;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="knockout-latest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" data-main="viewmodel" src="require.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="viewmodel.js"></script>
 </head> 
<body>
<form data-bind="submit: addItem">
    New item:
    <input data-bind='value: itemToAdd, valueUpdate: "afterkeydown"' />
    <button type="submit" data-bind="enable: itemToAdd().length > 0">Add</button>
    <p>Your items:</p>
    <select multiple="multiple" width="50" data-bind="options: items"> </select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting the following error: 
`require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module`

I would like to know how can I join the html pages with its viewmodel in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you posted, you have the links to the script files just listed on the page.  With RequireJS, the list of script files should be removed, and only RequireJS and the script used for the application entry point should be included in the page.  The application entry point can either be a `<script>` tag or as the `data-main` attribute in the RequireJS `<script>` tag.

I copied your code over to this [example in plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/PUmnprpqUMg9lOoiP2j0?p=preview).  I also moved the view model into a [knockout component](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-overview.html) and loaded the HTML using the [RequireJS text plugin](https://github.com/requirejs/text).  In main.js, there is a require.config() call that sets the paths for the text and knockout modules that point to a CDN.  The paths could point to local files also, but note that the `<script>` tags for knockout and text are not in the index.html file.  RequireJS will dynamically add them as it determines the dependencies based on the `define()` calls.